# import csv & use cell values one row at a time in loop

Tags: csv, loops, cells

I am trying to write a piece of code in python that will access the data in a csv file, take the values by row and iterate through these in a loop using the values in an expression before moving to the next.

My csv file has two columns and 298 rows, the first of which is the header.

I want to write something that says: for each row except the first (one at a time), set var1 to cell 1 and var2 to cell 2, then use these values to do something. After doing some research it doesn't seem as if I am able to do this directly from the csv file so I wrote an empty local array to hold the data. So far I have:

```
import csv
filename=open("pathway/filename.csv",'rb')
datareader=csv.reader(filename)
datareaderList=[]

for data in datareader:
    datareaderList.append(data)
```

This gives me an array populated with the data from the csv file contained within. When I print datareaderList I get [['Min',;Max'],['0','1'],['0',2'] etc.

I now want to be able to work through the list of data and access cells within a row to add them to a variable to use within an expression. I can't work out how to do this - in fact, I can't even work out how to get the values from individual positions within the data.

In text, what I want to code is:

```
for each row in the list of data:
    set var1 to cell position 2,1 (ie. 1st cell below header), var2 to cell position 2,2
        run con expression using var1 and var2 as variables
#iterate through each row of data in the list moving onto the next once the con expression is completed,
#i.e. next run var1 will be cell position 3,1, var2 will be cell position 3,2 etc.
```

If anyone has any ideas for how to do this I'd be really grateful as I am well and truly stuck! If you need more information or clarification let me know. Thanks in advance.